# Deploying BEAN in OSGi plugin

Tags: osgi, xpages

I am currently deploying my custom controls as OSGi plugins and I wanted to do the same thing with my beans. I have tried putting them into the OSGi plugin and it works fine but the only problem I have is the faces-config.

It seems it has to be called faces-config in the OSGi plugin to work but that means i can't use beans in the NSF anymore because it seems to ignore the local faces-config.

Is there a way to change the name of the faces-config in the OSGi plugin?

Something like FEATURE-faces-config.xml?

Comment: Could you clarify "it seems to ignore the local faces-config"? Do you mean that you tried having the Java class in the OSGi plugin and referencing that class in the NSF's faces-config, and that didn't work?

Comment: I have two beans. One deployed through OSGI plugin. I also put the faces-config file into the plugin into the WEB-INF folder. And then a BEAN in one of my NSF where i also want to use the BEAN from the pluging. In my NSF i put the bean into the "local" faces-config but it seems that its ignoring the local faces-config once i have one coming from the OSGI plugin.

Comment: Do they both have the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the class in your plugin that extends AbstractXspLibrary, you can override "getFacesConfigFiles", which should return an array of strings representing paths within the plugin to additional files of any name to load as faces-config additions. For example:

```
@Override
public String[] getFacesConfigFiles() {
    return new String[] {
        "com/example/config/beans.xml"
    };
}
```

Then you can put the config file in that path within your Java source folder (or another folder that is included in build.properties) and it will be loaded in addition to your app's normal faces-config, beans and all.

Answer (score 1):

The NSFs are running as separate, distinct Java applications. The OSGi plugin is running in the OSGi layer, above all those distinct Java applications, as a single code base. Consequently, the faces-config is only at that level.

It's possible to load them dynamically, by using an ImplicitObjectFactory, loaded from an XspContributor. That's what is done in OpenNTF Domino API for e.g. userScope (which is a bean stored in applicationScope of an NSF). See org.openntf.domino.xsp.helpers.OpenntfDominoImplicitObjectFactory, which is referenced in OpenntfDominoXspContributor, loaded via the extension point of type "com.ibm.xsp.library.Contributor".

A few caveats:

1. You have no control over what happens if you try to register your bean with a name the developer also uses for a different variable in that scope.
2. Unless you add code to check if the library is enabled, as we do, you'll be adding the bean to **every** database on the server.
3. You still need to add the library to the NSF. Unless you also provide a component that those databases will all use, there's no way you can programmatically add it, as far as I know.

It might be easier to skip the bean approach and just add an instance of the Java class in beforePageLoad, page controller class, or however you're managing the backing to the relevant XPage (if viewScope) or application (if sessionScope / applicationScope).